# Obtain Mangled Symbol Name based on C++ Signature

Tags: c++, function, naming

Does someone know how to obtain the mangled symbol name based on a given C++ function signature?
e.g.:

```
__stdcall unsigned char MyClass::MyFunc(const int param1, int param2);
```

would become:

```
?MyFunc@MyClass@@QGE@?BHH@Z
```

when using the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler.

I was thinking about some WINAPI-function, but I did not find any...

---

**EDIT:** Ok - I know, this is not a very clearly formulated question. What I want to achieve is the following:

```
GetMangledName("__stdcall unsigned char MyClass::MyFunc(const int param1, int param2);");
// Returns "?MyFunc@MyClass@@QGE@?BHH@Z"
```

Comment: What do you mean _(re-)decorate_? The mangled names are unique for the function parameter types, how they are mangled is compiler implementation specific and cannot be changed, unless you use different parameter types.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  I edited my question

Comment: Why is this tagged C#?

Comment: @crashmstr: because I thought of P/Invokation at the beginning (as my application is written in C#) - but I later thought, that I can also do this in pure C++ (but I forgot to remove the tag)..... I will edit my question

Comment: I don't think you can actually P/Invoke member functions (let alone create the C++ objects to call them with), which is one of the reasons why this did not make any sense. Building COM components from C++ or using C++/CLI are the two general ways to use an object oriented interface in C# (there are some other methods, like using SWIG).

Comment: I suspect the approach you intend to take will lead to a very circuitous route with kludgy processing to sew it together.   It might help you to get a useful answer if you described why you are going this route and what the overall end goal is.  From what you have described, I suspect a table of function pointers will get you closer and not require any disreputable MSVC version dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the name mangling is compiler dependent and not part of the c++ specification. So as far as I can see the only reliable way is to invoke the actual compiler that you are using and get back a mapping of how the source names map to the mangled names.